# Floating DIV Extra Space Fillup

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have these floating DIV boxes in which works perfectly. :)

[image: float div]

but when the text extends more, I encounter this float problem.

[image]

How do I fill that ugly space thats' ruining my design?

Answer (score 3):

This happens because floated elements fall out of the normal HTML document flow and default to this behaviour when some elements are taller than their siblings.

One way to solve this is to have fixed height elements. If they all have the same height this issue will not occur. This is not always practical, however, especially with dynamic content.

Another solution is to use JavaScript. Take a look at the [Masonry jQuery plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/); it can do what you need.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I will try to look at that. Are there jQuery solutions for this problem?

Comment: @JoshuaLangit123 The Masonry plugin is a jQuery solution. Did you mean a non-jQuery solution?

Comment: I got Masonry. However, I am having troubles with it. Nothing happens after I implement it. How do we use it?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Vanilla Masonry plugin which won't rely on jQuery; http://vanilla-masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 0):

A non-JS solution for this is to use `display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;` instead of `float: left` on those boxes. That will make them all sit side by side and line up nicely, although there will be small gaps below any boxes that have a taller one beside them. `inline-block` will at least stop the float snagging you are seeing.

Comment: hello, display:inline-block can be seen as a fall back for IE if you use column-count ;)

Comment: This is a nice non-js solution @ralph.m . However, as what you said, there are small gaps, but the gaps are not uniform, which makes it still kind of ugly. Here's a screenshot.
http://i5.minus.com/jL6sxYjF1pZj9.png

Comment: I think this is the best answer that I got. I just have to remove the background color, and add a top border, and it looks nice. THanks. :D

Comment: Yes, those gaps are what I mentioned in my post. `inline-block` stops the problem you had of the floats hooking on each other, but if the boxes aren't the same height, there will be gaps under the shorter ones. Glad you found a way around it, anyhow.