# Vertically stack divs in different columns css only

Tags: css

I have divs with same width but different heights, they should be displayed in columns, floating up to the next div above them.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kaljak/DAYSk/

```
Is there any way to handle that without placing them via Javascript?
```

One idea of mine would be to have divs for the columns and place the divs into them, but is there another possibility without adding more markup?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know if you can do that with css only. But you can achieve that via js (I know you don't want to use it): http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: @kaljak:you need to add a wrapper div for each column which then contains the child div's of variable height.

Comment: @MohitPandey OP thought of that solution already; he doesn't want extra markup.

Comment: thank you guys, that was also the 2 things I was thinking about, check out the answer with the css-columns, I didn't know about them before :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another possible solution is to use CSS columns. Apply the columns property to the container

```
body {
    -moz-column-width: 100px;
    -webkit-column-width: 100px;
    column-width: 100px;
}
```

Then use `display: inline-block;` on the `div`s.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tdwZe/

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts

Note: CSS columns are not supported in IE older than IE10 (http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn).

Comment: Very interesting answer, it is working, not handling older then IE10 is a big drawback.. Thanks nevertheless :)

Answer (score 2):

You can, but you would need to place those boxes in parent boxes

**demo** http://jsbin.com/ozazat/3/edit

For example 3 columns, each holding as many boxes as you wish:

```
div div {
  background-color:red;
  margin:10px;
}
.col1, .col2, .col3 {
  width:100px;
  float:left;
  border:solid;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="col1">
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="col2">

        <div>text<br>text</div>
    <div>text</div>

  </div>  
  <div class="col3">
        <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use absolute positions. Assuming you know the heights of your divs. This solution does not work well for dynamic content.

You will need to assign a class to each div, then provide the relevant CSS to position it correctly.

```
div1 {
  height: 100;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; 
  top: 0;
}

div2 {
  height: 100;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; 
  top: 100px; /* The height of the div above it */
}
```

Etc...

If you do have dynamic content, it may be better to use JavaScript, in particular the [jQuery Masonry Plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Another way to do this is, like you mentioned, stack your divs in columns.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907949/floating-div-extra-space-fillup/16907969#16907969) for more details.

Comment: Well the divs have variable height (content varies) so that's not possible, right? (you would need js?)

Comment: I updated my answer. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907949/floating-div-extra-space-fillup/16907969#16907969

Answer (score 0):

Use float:left for every div then for every odd div use clear:left. This will work cross browser except for using odd-child. You would have to add extra markup and divine an I'd for that. There's no way around that one unfortunately